# wrong result in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio

I'm trying to learn LINQ , many Tutorials start with such a code snippet:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 1,128,1569,136,658,1455,145 };
        var items=
            from item in numbers 
            select item;
                  foreach(var item in items)
                  label1.Text+=items.ToString() +"\n";
    }
```

and the result is expected to be:

```
1
128
1596
...
```

but the real result is this (!):
[image]

what could be causing this?
is this a wrong result actually?

Comment: I think you want `item.ToString()` not `items.ToString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a minor typo in you code:

```
foreach(var item in items)
    label1.Text+=items.ToString() +"\n";
```

should be

```
foreach(var item in items)
    label1.Text+=item.ToString() +"\n"; //items => item
```

P.S.: Do you know [LINQPad](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linqpad.net%2F&ei=XfrQU9bDF4v64QTA0IHYCQ&usg=AFQjCNFw-ZpPkP4je7u9udiur5Wg5us7tQ&sig2=mp_r2dIsUwCj8id3lQbSRw&bvm=bv.71667212,d.bGE)? Great tool for such small "learning exercises"...

Comment: thanks for your Link for LINQ !

Answer (score 5):

Use `item` instead of `items` in your foreach loop.

```
 foreach(var item in items)
      label1.Text += item  + "\n";
```

You can also do that in one line:

```
label1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `items` to `item`:

```
  label1.Text += item.ToString() +"\n";
```